# How do I make a current-controlled switch or where do I buy one?

Tags: switches

I am making something that requires a 400 V capacitor to be dumped into something at once. It is controlled by an Arduino Uno.

I need the circuits to be separate, but when I send a current through one part of the switch it should close it for the capacitor to dump its electricity; a switch that is closed by a current instead of flipping a switch. How do I do this? What is it called, and where do I buy it?

Comment: Sounds like a relay.

Comment: can i run a high voltage and low voltage through it and they wont affect eachother?

Comment: You can have a relay control a high voltage with a low voltage or control a low voltage with a high voltage. Just check what the coil accepts and what the contacts are rated to.

Comment: would a solenoid pressing a button work well? how fast would that be.

Comment: `solenoid pressing a button` ... that's a relay

Comment: yes i know but im saying for high voltage

Comment: i would use a high voltage button

Comment: Use an SCR. Trigger it with an optoisolator of you're nervous about letting the magic smoke escape from your Arduino.

Comment: If you have a button that works, and a solenoid that works, you can also literally make the solenoid press the button as you suggested. It's just that you can buy this in one part (a relay) and you can also find non-mechanical switching devices (various kinds of transistors)... but if it's stupid and it works, it's not stupid

Answer (score 4):

You need to figure out the peak current, then you can look online for parts that meet the requirements.

There are tons of different switching devices that can be controlled by an arduino and switch 400V.

Relays, solid state relays, SCRs, IGBTs, and MOSFETs could all potentially fit the bill.

Just a guess, without knowing the details: A SCR is probably what you're looking for. They're cheap and easy to use with good power ratings, the downside is that they can't be turned off once the current is flowing.